# Non RLT-Cutting planes for nonconvex QPs?

Tags: quadratic-programming

Consider a general nonconvex QP $x^\top Qx$. This can be linearized in an extended space by using the variable $Y=xx^\top$.

Now a valid inequality $a^\top x \le b$ can be strengthend by the RLT procedure by multiplying with some $x_j$ to obtain $a^\top y \le bx_j$. See for example [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/cuts/38_RLTcuts.html).

Are there other approaches than RLT in the context of nonconvex qps to strengthen a given inequality?

Answer (score 2):

One such paradigm is *intersection cuts*.
It's a widely used framework in mixed-integer programming, and it naturally extends to non-convex nonlinear settings as well.

A (very) recent work on this topic: [On the implementation and strengthening of intersection cuts for QCQPs](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/index/index/docId/7999).